# Explain why the two ODEs are equivalent

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, self-learning

I would like to ask the following question:
Suppose I have a second order ODE and I split it into a system of two first order ODEs. I find the general solution of the second order ODE directly and I also computed the general solution of the system of two first order ODEs. I am asking to explain why both general solutions are equivalent.

I found that the eigenvalues as well as the solutions to the characteristic equation (when solving directly the linear second order ODE) are the same. Shall I make any statements for the arbitrary constants? What explanation shall I include for the question I stated above?

Thank you.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'split it'. If you mean that you let, say, $x_1 = y, x_2 = y'$ then you can show that the map $y \mapsto (y, y')$ is an invertible linear map between the solutions.